# Protractor : PhpStorm IDE pointing to default conf.js file

Tags: selenium, protractor, phpstorm, webstorm

I am trying to run a basic Protractor script in PhpStorm IDE on Ubuntu. When I run the conf file, it throws this below error.

```
Usage: protractor [configFile] [options]
configFile defaults to protractor.conf.js
The [options] object will override values from the config file.
See the reference config for a full list of options.

Error: Error: more than one config file specified
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js:163:15
```

I am not able to figure why it points to the default conf file instead of what I have specified.

**Here is a screenshot of the configuration**

[image: PhpStorm error]

**c_conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', 
    specs: [spec.js],
    framework : 'jasmine',

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
}
```

**spec.js**

```
describe('Protractor Framework', function(){
    it('Title', function(){
        browser.get('https://www.google.com');
    })
})
```

Comment: What about this way: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/protractor.html 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/run-debug-configuration-protractor.html

Answer (score 1):

You did wrong setting, please reference settings in below screenshot:

- `Node interpreter` is to specify the nodejs binary
- `Node parameters` is **optional**, to specify parameter for nodejs binary
- `JavaScript file` must be the `cli.js` of protractor\build
- `Application parameters` is to specify conf file and params as you typed in cmd line
- `Environment variables` is **optional**

[image]

Comment: I am using ubuntu.